# py2exe/pyinstaller: execution failure

Tags: python, wxpython

I programmed a simple, little game with wxpython and created an .exe of it with py2exe (and in a 2nd try with pyinstaller). I also programmed an installer which just creates a folder and copies all the game files into this folder. I also created an .exe for this installer. Everything works fine on Windows 7. But on Windows XP i get this problem: My installer.exe succesfully works, but when I start the .exe from my game then I get this error:

> foo.exe is not a valid win32 application

I use python 2.7

Comment: Is the version of Python 2.7 on your Windows 7 machine 32-bit or 64-bit?  Is your Windows XP machine 32-bit or 64-bit?  My guess is that you've got an architecture mismatch.

Comment: oh yes, python and win7 are 64bit, winXP is 32bit. But why does my installer.exe work on XP ??

Answer (score 0):

Is the Windows 7 box you're using to create the installer 64-bit? Is the Python version you were using on Windows 7 64-bit? If so, then you'll need to create the exe using a 32-bit Python, 32-bit wxPython and 32-bit installer.

A 64-bit program will run just fine on a 64-bit system, but it won't work on a 32-bit one. However, a 32-bit program will run on both.

Comment: thank you, i will try it later. But as I asked above: Why does my installer.exe work on XP ? It was also created with win7(64bit)/Python(64bit)

Comment: You don't say what you used for your installer. It's possible the installer produces a 32-bit installer that just sticks your 64-bit exe(s) on your machine. In fact, I think that's exactly what it's doing. You used a 32-bit installer app to package up your 64-bit exe.